# Python UDP Communication over unidentified network

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, udp, fpga

I am using Python to send UDP packets to an FPGA board and am fairly new to python. I am using wireshark to monitor the packets being sent and I know the the FPGA is receiving all the packets correctly. The problem is with what packets are being sent. The computer does not recognize what the FPGA is when it is connected so it leaves it as an unidentified network and assigns it an IP address (169.254.233.200). I am using this code to try and send a UDP packet that simply says "Test" to the FPGA (Sorry for the terrible formatting).

```
import sys

import socket

def main():

    UDP_IP="169.254.233.201"
    UDP_PORT=9
    MESSAGE='Test'

    print ("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
    print ("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
    print ("message:", MESSAGE)
    sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM ) # UDP
    sock.sendto( bytes(MESSAGE, 'UTF-8'), (bytes(UDP_IP, 'UTF-8'), UDP_PORT) )
```

However, instead of sending a UDP packet when this script is run, the computer broadcasts a message saying "Who has 169.254.233.201?  Tell 169.254.233.200". I'm guessing this a problem caused by the unidentified network, or I am just addressing the packet incorrectly. I am trying to keep the HDL on the FPGA as simple as possible, so I would prefer if it didn't have to send any packets to the computer to verify the connection. This is why I wanted to use UDP over TCP.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Graeme

SOLVED: I noticed that the computer was sending messages to port 169.254.255.255 when trying to set up the connection. I changed UDP_IP="169.254.233.201" to UDP_IP="169.254.255.255" and the UDP packets started going through.

LESSON: I am bad at IP addresses.

Comment: Does the FPGA implements an IP stack? What is the ip of your FPGA? How is it connected to your computer ?

Comment: The board is connected via Ethernet. I'm not to familiar with IP stacks, but the board has a pre-programmed microprocessor that handles the connection between the computer and the FPGA. However, I don't believe that it sends anything back to the computer on its own and I am not sending anything back to the computer in my logic. I would also prefer to keep it this way to reduce the number of logic elements used.

Comment: "board has a pre-programmed microprocessor that handles the connection between the computer and the FPGA" How is the connection supposed to be made? Over serial, ethernet, usb ? You get a default ip because the board has no DHCP server, hence why sending to 169.254.233.201 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference/future readers, the problem was the your FPGA lacks the ARP protocol support.

The Ethernet frames cannot be sent directly to IP address, only to the MAC address. Thus, the sender computer must somehow learn IP<->MAC address mapping. Normally, the "ARP" protocol does that -- the message `"Who has 169.254.233.201? Tell 169.254.233.200".` is ARP request.
The proper workaround is to add ARP entry manually, for example on Linux, one would write `arp -s 169.254.233.201 00:00:11:22:33:44` to tell computer the MAC address of the FPGA board. Even better way is to teach FPGA board to respond with proper ARP reply.

The address 169.254.255.255 is a "broadcast address", which goes to all computers at once (hence no need for ARP). This is OK to use for testing, but if you were to put it to large network and send a lot of traffic, then this traffic will be received by every computer on the network (i.e. it will drain battery on your ipad faster if you put it on home network)